# using Array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays

My first question here.
I am using an array of pointers instead of a 2D array. Now, to display an element I can use   *(arr[i]+j), where arr is the array i denotes the row and j denotes the column. However, when I try to assign a value to any element using the same notation the code stops working. I dont get a compilation error but when I run it it just stops working. Could anybody help me?

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i,j,k;
    char temp2, temp, *arr[] = {
        "Brinda Roy", 
        "Rakesh Bai", 
        "Neha Saxen", 
        "Ankit Jain"};

    printf("%c",*(arr[3]+8));

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=0, k=9; j<=4, k>=5; j++, k--){
            temp =*(arr[i]+j);
            *(arr[i]+j)=*(arr[i]+k);
            *(arr[i]+k)=temp;
        }

    }

    printf("\nThe array is ");

    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
        printf("\n%s",arr[i]);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Open your debugger and inspect the values of your counters when the problem occurs.  It will probably be very obvious what the issue is.

Comment: An array of pointers is just a 2D-array. `arr[i]` is equivalent to `*(arr+i)`.

Comment: Your error might be a segmentation fault error, which means the array is going out of bounds somewhere. It usually occurs when your playing with pointers. Try debugging your code.

Comment: I have a problem with this line `for(j=0, k=9; j<=4, k>=5; j++, k--)` more specifically these exact characters `j<=4, k>=5`. What exactly do you expect to happen here? The comma operator will cause the for loop to only check the right most comparison.

Comment: Your code is like doing this: `int *j = &2; *j = 3;`. Where is the number you are trying to change stored? If a pointer points to a constant, you can't de-reference it and modify the result!

Comment: Note that `*(arr[i]+j)` is exactly equivalent to `arr[i][j]`

Comment: @Trevor not quite; a 2D array must be square, contiguous, and has no "column" of row pointers (making it take less space).

Answer (score 5):

The runtime crash is due to you modifying the string literals in `arr`. The string literals `"Brinda Roy"`, `"Rakesh Bai"`, `"Neha Saxen"` and `"Ankit Jain"` should be treated as `const char[]`, as they may be stored in a read-only section of your program. Attempting to change their values causes undefined behaviour, as mentioned in the comments below.

If you want to edit these read-only strings, you're going to need to make copies of them into non-`const` buffers.

If you do:

```
char *str = "message"
```

you shouldn't modify the data pointed to by `str` because it's pointing to read-only memory.

If you do:

```
char str[] = "message"
```

you *can* modify the data pointed to by `str` because the read-only string literal `"message"` is being *copied* into the array `str`.

Your code falls into the first scenario above.

Comment: Minor nit, the string literals may be stored in read-only section.  Writing to them is undefined behavior, and the compiler is free to put them into writable memory.

Comment: @Michael: Yeah that's a better way of putting it.

Answer (score 3):

C allows strings defined in the source via this style to be stored in a read-only data section. Check this output:

```
$ cat storage.c
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char *arr[] = {"hello", "world"};
    arr[1][1]='a';
    return 0;
}
$ make storage
cc     storage.c   -o storage
$ readelf -p.rodata storage

String dump of section '.rodata':
  [     4]  hello
  [     a]  world
```

My compiler has placed the strings into the `.rodata` read-only data section. When I try to update the `o` to an `a` in the program, the program dies:

```
$ ./storage 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is general applies to any code that defines strings as the following:

```
char *foo = "string";
```

If you want to create a modifiable string in the program source, you'd write it instead like this:

```
char foo[] = "string";
```

I'm not entire sure what the syntax would be to create an array of modifiable strings; at least the following *ugly* approach works, but I'm sure there's something better:

```
char a1[] = "hello";
char a2[] = "world";
char *arr[] = {a1, a2};
```

Comment: Ah So, instead of using an array of pointers, if I use a pointer to an array I would be able to modify the strings right?

Comment: Note that the last line in my answer builds an array of pointers-to-char -- it isn't a pointer to an array.

Comment: Oh yeah. I see your point. Let me try it and get back to you. 
EDIT-It's working. Thanks. But is there a way to not declare separate arrays for each string?

Comment: The only way I've found is something even worse: `char arr[][4] = {{'h', 'i', 0}, {'m', 'o', 'm', 0}};`. You have to know how long the longest string is -- and it allocates that much space for _every_ string.

Answer (score 2):

You try to modify string literals. This is forbidden. Note that even though this is not enforced by the type system (`"abc"` is not `const char*`), modifying a character literal `"abc"[1]='c'` leads to undefined behavior.

You have to move your data to a writable location. The easiest, though nonstandard way of doing this would be using the `strdup` function:

```
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
  arr[i]=strdup(arr[i]);
```

That will allocate memory on the heap for the string and copy the string to it. If you don't have the `strdup` function, you have to implement it using `malloc`, `strlen` and `memcpy`.

Note that as always with dynamically allocated memory, you have to free it; otherwise, you get a memory leak.

BTW the normal way to access both double pointer arrays and multidimensional arrays is `arr[i][j]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just wanted to practice array of pointers so I tried to modify all my 2D array codes to array of pointers. I do know about arr[i][j] notation.Did not know about string literals. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the memory reserved this way:

```
{"Brinda Roy", 
 "Rakesh Bai", 
 "Neha Saxen", 
 "Ankit Jain"};
```

When you define a char* this way, it is only read memory.